# Swift recursive closure stack overflow bug

Tags: swift, recursion, closures, stack-overflow

Update: It should be noted that the question below is of academic nature and the use of core location, or the polling of location data is not relevant to the question - the proper way to do this is always through the core location delegate method. My original question eventually boiled down to: "Is infinite recursion ever possible in swift? (or tail recursion)". The answer to this is no. This is what caused my error due to stack space exhaustion.

Original question:
I'm having an issue with a recursive function that passes values through a closure. I'm a longtime Objective-C developer but have not been programming in Swift long, so maybe I'm missing something obvious. Here is the function and how I'm calling it:

```
public func getLocation(completion: @escaping (CLLocationCoordinate2D?) -> ())
{
    completion(self.currentLocation)
    weak var weakSelf = self
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        weakSelf?.getLocation(completion: {location in
            completion(weakSelf?.currentLocation)
        })
    }
}

LocationManager.shared.getLocation(completion: {location in
        if(location != nil)
        {
            weakSelf?.lonLabel.text = "Lat: " + location!.latitude.description
            weakSelf?.latLabel.text = "Lon: " + location!.longitude.description
        }
    })
```

The bug (description `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f1b7fd0)`) I'm getting after running for a period of time is this:

[image]

What I'm trying to accomplish is pass an auto-updating location value to a location manager object. I'm thinking another way to accomplish is with `performSelector withObject afterDelay` but at this point, I'm just wondering why this is crashing?

Comment: You are calling `getLocation` which calls `getLocation` which calls `getLocation` which calls `getLocation` which calls `getLocation` which calls... What do you expect?

Comment: Why not use a repeating `Timer` and avoid the recursion?

Comment: @rmaddy Or a `DispatchSourceTimer`

Comment: That's exactly what I expect it to, but it's after a delay 0.1 second delay (an arbitrary number for testing). What I didn't expect is the crash - why would this cause it to crash?

Comment: @SolsmaDev Because every recursive call allocates a new stack frame (memory on the stack which holds local variables, and the return address). The calls are never exited, so you eventually run out of stack space.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Alexander, is there any way to accomplish this recursively without exhausting stack space? I'm aware there are other ways to accomplish this task, I'm just curious at this point.

Comment: And what is `getLocation` actually doing?   The CoreLocation manager updates the location periodically in its delegate method. By the way, this is Swift. `weakSelf` is redundant because `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` does not cause a retain cycle.

Comment: Ok, thats also helpful @vadian, I only made a weak reference grasping for straws on what was causing the bug in the first place. getLocation is just passing the current device location repeatedly. I'm aware there are better ways to do this.

Comment: @SolsmaDev No. By definition, you have an infinite recursion. You're calling this for an unbounded amount of time. Sooner or later, it will run out of memory.

Comment: Rob, in my comment below I said "I'm also aware of that, I'm getting the location value from the delegate in the first place - I feel like I should be more explicit that this was only an academic exercise based out of curiosity"

Comment: @Rob for the basis of this experiment, a location value seemed like a good continually changing number to be polling. I got the value from the delegate in the first place.

Comment: I updated the question to make this more obvious. I can't think of an example of when polling makes sense, but my guess is that low level apis (like Core Location) use polling to measure the sensor values that are eventually processed and passed through the delegates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're causing a stack overflow, by having `getLocation(completion:)` call `getLocation(completion:)`, which calls `getLocation(completion:)`, ... until you run out of stack space.

You could use a `DispatchSourceTimer` instead:

```
import Dispatch

let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
timer.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: .seconds(5), leeway: .milliseconds(100))

timer.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self,
          let location = LocationManager.shared.currentLocation else { return }
    strongSelf.lonLabel.text = "Lat: \(location.latitude)"
    strongSelf.latLabel.text = "Lon: \(location.longitude)"
}

timer.resume()
```

But this whole polling approach just doesn't make any sense. Your location delegate is already being informed of location changes. You can just change your labels then.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander I just looked up `DispatchSourceTimer` and that looks exactly like what I was looking for. Do you know if this existed in Objective-C? I've never used it before.

Comment: @SolsmaDev It did, but it was tucked away in a whole slew of messy api.

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, none of this should be done. Just use the proper delegate method to update the label when the user's location changes. It's pointless to update the label far more frequently than the location is being updated.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, agreed

Comment: @SolsmaDev Seriously though, don't use this. I'm just illustrating how to to asynchronously trigger a repeating event. Use the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods instead to be informed of new locations as their made available, and have your labels update accordingly

Comment: @rmaddy, I'm also aware of that, I'm getting the location value from the delegate in the first place - I feel like I should be more explicit that this was only an academic exercise based out of curiosity.

Comment: @Alexander, right, that's what I'm using - a location value just seemed like a good updating value for testing purposes.

Comment: I guess this could have boiled down to the more generic "can there ever be a case of infinite recursion that doesn't cause a crash" to which I learned definitively that the answer is no due to stack space exhaustion!

Comment: @SolsmaDev Now, that's for the general case. For a limit class of recursion, called [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), it is possible to have infinite recursion without exhausting stack space, *if* the compiler supports tail call optimization, which Swift and other ARC'ed languages (python) do not.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the insight. I was just looking into tail recursion and if there were any Swift examples, so that answered my next question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162928/discussion-between-alexander-and-solsma-dev).

Comment: @Rob Gets me every time :')